# how to fix jquery datatable fixed columns not working on initial load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I've been using jquery Datatable with fixed columns as one of the features needed.

however on initial loading of the table, the fixed columns is not working and the paging buttons are on top of the headers. the issues are fixed once I click on any numbers on the length dropdown of the paging feature.

here are the images:

table on load - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE93w.jpg

table after clicking any function of the dataTable - https://i.stack.imgur.com/25N95.jpg

here's the code i used: just the one from the dataTable example

```
table = $('#example').DataTable({
            scrollX: "100%",
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: true,
            fixedColumns: {
                leftColumns: 3
            }
        });
```

Here's my html

```
<div class="tab-content container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="" class="tab-pane active">
            <table class="table">
                <thead></thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
</div></div></div>
```

i haven't used any customized css yet. Can anybody shed light on this please. Thanks

Comment: is  the table visible or in a tab not yet visible?

Comment: its in a tab and not yet visible unless clicked.

Comment: this thread on the datatables forum will probably be of help https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/114413/#Comment_114413 It provides two ways to fix this

Comment: thanks a lot! will check this out and give an update. thanks!

Comment: That solution is for jquery.ui but the same thing can be done with the bootstrap tab events

Comment: i used the solution, and it works. however, the fixed columns are a little bit higher than the scrollable ones on load.

Answer (score 0):

You have indicated in comments that your table is initially hidden and is located in the tab.

You need to use the following code once table becomes visible.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
    $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
        .columns.adjust()
        .fixedColumns().relayout();
});
```

See [`fixedColumns().relayout()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/fixedColumns().relayout()) API method for more information.

See [jQuery DataTables: Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/#example4) article for more details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I use this when I have datatables in a tab:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui){
            var selectedTab = ui.newTab.index();

            if (selectedTab == 0) { //first tab (datatable 1)
                $dataTable1.columns.adjust().draw();
            }

            if (selectedTab == 1) { //second tab (datatable 2)
                $dataTable2.columns.adjust().draw();
            }

        }
    });
```